# Insert NULL into database with pdo

Tags: php, database, pdo

in the database I'm working with, there's a table named "packets", in this table there are columns like "id", "userid" etc. and a column named "usage"(I know its a poor choice of name cause usage is a reserved word, but sadly I may not change anything in the table), the type of this column is enum with 3 values("education", "study" and "advanced training") with "education" as default-value and the value can be NULL.

I wrote a class Packet with getters/setters like `set_usage($usage)/get_usage()` and a class Packet_dao for accessing database using pdo:

```
class Packet_dao {
    private m_insert_query;
    ...
    public function persist($data)
    {
        $query = $this->m_insert_query;
        try
        {
           $stmt = $this->bind_param($data, $query);
           $stmt->execute();
           return true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex)
        {
           $this->m_error_message = $ex->getMessage();
           return false;
        }
    }

    private function bind_param($packet, $query)
    {
       $stmt = $this->m_pdo->prepare($query);
       $stmt->bindParam(':userId', $packet->get_user_id());
       ...
       $stmt->bindParam(':usage', $packet->get_usage());
       return $stmt;
    }
```

insert query would looks like

```
INSERT INTO packets (userId, number, ..., `usage`) 
VALUES (:userId, Coalesce(:number, default(number)), Coalesce(:usage, default(`usage`)))
```

so if I want to add a packet into db, the code would looks like:

```
$packet = new Packet();
$packet_dao = new Packet_dao();
$packet->set_stuff("stuff");
$packet_dao->persist($packet);
```

so far, so good, everything is working fine.

now, another usage-case "fullversion" should be added, and instead of adding a new value to the enum, they decided to use NULL as value of usage for packets which are full version. Now I get a problem: when I try to set value for usage using `$packet->set_usage(NULL)`, it will be interpreted as the same as if the value isn't set and the default value("education") will be set in this case.  What should I do?

Comment: If a value is a `null`, then the third parameter for the `bindValue` or `bindParam` should be `\PDO::PARAM_NULL`. That means you'll have to check the value before adding it to `bindParam`.

Comment: `INSERT INTO packets (userId, number, ..., 'usage')` if that is your actual code you're using with the `'` quotes around the `usage` column, then you need to use ticks `\``. Those are 2 different animals altogether and will throw a syntax error. If you are using ticks, you should modify your question then, in order to avoid confusion for people who may think that that is the problem and may want to post an answer in regards to just that alone.

Comment: @fred: yeah I know, I just didnt know how to escape ` here, edited

Comment: Try it with quotes: `$packet->set_usage("NULL")` I think that should work. Because right now, you are trying to enter the NULL constant, rather than the string, resulting in a just that; a NULL value/empty.

Comment: @N.B. sorry, but I think I need more help there :-/. There are 2 cases now: 1. it's a education version, so I wont use $packet->set_usage() and let it take the default value($packet->get_usage() will return NULL) 2. its a fullversion, I need to set the value of usage to NULL. in both case, the value to bind is NULL, how can I tell the insert query to make a difference?

Comment: @Fred: already tried it, doesnt work, cause $packet->set_usage("NULL") will set the value to a string, since the type of the column is enum and "NULL" is not an accepted value, it will leave the column empty.

Comment: Then try using a pre-defined variable and bind to that. `$var = NULL;` as per http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Comment: `$usage = NULL $packet->set_usage($usage)` give the same result as when I don't set the value => take default value "education" :-/

Comment: Using an optional NULL value with a non-NULL default value seems a bad choice / combination. Can't you remove the default value / set it to NULL? I'm not sure there is another workaround.

Comment: @jeroen: sadly, I may not change ANYTHING in the database :-(

Comment: *Hm...* not sure if `$usage = NULL $packet->set_usage($usage)` is proper syntax. Try a ternary operator instead.

Comment: what do you mean? The problem is, like I wrote in my comment to N.B. in both case (I need default case => not using set_usage => value of usage is NULL, OR I want to set the value of usage to actual NULL) the value of usage is NULL and the database can't tell the difference to take default as value(case 1) or NULL as value(case 2)

Answer (score 0):

apparently, the 2nd parameter of Coalesce() force it to take the default value when nothing is set (or NULL), after I changed `Coalesce(:usage, default(usage))` into `:usage`. It worked